# connect xls to mysql on web [dumb question but maybe possible?

Tags: mysql, excel, database, odbc

So excel can connect via ODBC to local dbms, pulled data back with a simple SELECT stmt. I have a Mysql dbms running on the web... can I connect via odbc locally on my home laptop to my web-based dbms? I'm running API to populate my web-based dbms and want to pull that data in excel locally. Not sure if possible.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197742/connect-to-online-mysql-database-using-vba

Comment: As long as the database is accessible remotely, then it's possible. But this question is much more suitable at [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).